# Backup of SQL Server database without timestamps

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups

I'm using the following line to backup a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName WITH COMPRESSION
```

Given that database is not changing, repeated execution of this line yields files that are of the same size, but are massively different inside.

How do I create repeated SQL Server backups of the same unchanged database that would give same byte-accurate files? I guess that simple `BACKUP DATABASE` invocations add some timestamps or some other meta information in the backup media, is there a way to disable or strip this addition?

Alternatively, if it's not possible, is there a relatively simple way to compare 2 backups and see if they'll restore of the exactly same state of the database?

**UPDATE**: My point for backup comparison is that I'm backing up myriads of databases daily, but most databases don't change that often. It's normal for most of them to change several time per year. So, basically, for all other DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Mongo), I'm using the following algorithm:

- Do a new daily backup
- Diff new backup with the most recent of the old backups
- If the database wasn't changed (i.e. backups match), delete the new daily backup I've just created

This algorithm works with all DBMSes we've encountered before, but, alas, it fails because of non-repeatable MSSQL backups.

Answer (score 0):

As you guess part of the backup catalog includes the date and time of the backup. The [`WITH COMPRESSION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx) option compresses the backup to save space but a little change in the file will cause changes throughout the file because of the way compression algorithms work.

If you don't want so many differences then remove the compress option, but comparing backup files isn't the way to go.

If you have a database that changes little then incremental or differential backups may be of more use.

However you seem to have fallen into a classic trap called the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you are asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.  What is prompting you to try and compare databases?

Comment: I've tried to omit compression, it doesn't help - files still differ. My original intent for this comparison was backup optimization, I've added detailed description of my backup algorithm in the question.

Comment: The metadata information is being written to the media header using Microsoft Tape format, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178062.aspx I don't think there is a way to separate the two unless you use a 3rd party backup tool.

Comment: Is there a way to work it around? For example, to compute some sort of a hash that would show that state of the database has changed?

Comment: Always replace the old backup with the most recent.